# How can I get my React Context's default value to be set to my localStorage before react-router-dom renders my component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom, higher-order-functions, react-context

I am trying to handle client-side authentication for users, and I have managed to use Context to log a user in or out - however, Contexts do not persist on a page refresh. I'm using Context because I want my header to change based on if the user is logged in, and I want react-router-dom to route based on if the user is logged in.

As a result, I am trying to utilize localStorage in order to set my default value:

```
function App() {
    const [isAuthorized, setIsAuthorized] = useState(window.localStorage.getItem('auth'))
    const value = { isAuthorized, setIsAuthorized};

    return (
        <AuthorizedContext.Provider value={value}>
            <div className='app'>
                {<Routing/>}
            </div>
        </AuthorizedContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

And then in my Routing, use that context to determine if a user should be given access to the component or be pushed away to my login page

```
function Routing() {
    const {isAuthorized} = useContext(AuthorizedContext)

    //Return component only if logged in
    const withSecure = (Component) => (props) =>  (
        isAuthorized === true
            ?
                <Component {...props} />
            :
                <Redirect to='/login'/>
    )

    //Return with header if requested
    const withHeader = (Component) => (props) => (
        <>
            <Header />
            <Component {...props} />
        </>
    )

    //Do both of these methods, i.e withSecure(withHeader())
    const withSecureRendering = compose(
        withSecure,
        withHeader
    )

    return (
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" render={withSecureRendering(Homepage)} />
                <Route exact path="/recipies" render={withSecureRendering(Recipies)} />
                <Route exact path="/pantry" render={withSecureRendering(Pantry)} />
                <Route exact path="/login" render={withHeader(Login)} />
                <Route exact path="/signup" render={withHeader(SignUp)} />
                <Route path="*" render={withHeader(NotFound)} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

My Context is very simple:

```
export default React.createContext()
```

(I have tried to set the default value here as well, but nothing changed so, for the time being, I removed it.)

So as the title says, how can I get my Context's default value to be set to my localStorage before react-router-dom renders my component?

Comment: Not quite an answer to your question, but you might consider setting up a PrivateRoute component. The idea is to wrap all of the routes that require user authentication in the PrivateRoute component. The PrivateRoute component will check if the user is authenticated - if they are then it renders the component. If not then it redirects them to a login page. Here is a good explanation: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/ , and here is a code another example: https://github.com/lhendriks1/askify-app/blob/master/src/components/Utils/PrivateRoute.js

Comment: I believe this implementation has the same issue, where the fake method 'is authenticated' needs to default to a value. That way once a page refreshes, the default value is used because the Context doesn't save. But trying to use localStorage for the default value there has the same issue of not being correct, sadly.

Comment: It doesn't have to default to a value. You can check local storage for the key each time before a private route is accessed: !!window.localStorage.getItem(NameofYourtTokenKey); if true then render the component of the private route; if false then redirect the user to login

Comment: I ended up doing it that way, and it does work. The reason why I was trying to use a default value is that I was hoping I could use a React Context in my login, change it and it changes my header. And so when I refresh a page, I need that Context to be defaulted correctly - else i need to refresh my page for my context to update. However, I just ended up having my log in and log out routings use href (refreshing the page) instead of the react-router-dom.

Comment: You can still use context to make the header show different things based on login status. Put a 'loginStatus' variable in your context and pass it to your nav component. Have your nav conditionally render its content based on 'loginStatus'. Ex: https://github.com/lhendriks1/askify-app/blob/master/src/contexts/AuthContext.js

Comment: ....oh I finally understand what you are saying. You could check the token when the app loads (for a refresh) and immediately use a call back to update the login status in context.

Comment: That would work too I bet, thank you